# Group theory with matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider GL($2,\Bbb{R})$, the group of 2 by 2 invertible matrices with entries in R
under matrix multiplication. Let T be the subgroup of GL$(2,\Bbb{R})$ generated
by 
$ A= \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) $ and $B=\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

Show that T has 8 elements.

I have no clue on how to begin this question. Please advise.

Comment: Did you try computing products of the matrices and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe the following:
\begin{align*}
A^2 &= -I \\
B^2 &= I \\
AB &= -BA = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array} \right).
\end{align*}
Now, given a word in $A$ and $B$, using the first two relations, we may always reduce it so that no powers of $A$ or $B$ of two or greater are in it. I.e. the word $A^3B^5A^2$ will be equal to $AB$. The second relation allows us to reduce words that have alternating blocks of $A$'s and $B$'s into one with having a single block of $A$'s and then a single block of $B$'s. I.e. $ABAB^2$ will be equal to $-BA^2B^2$, which will then be equal to $B$. Thus, given any word in $A$ and $B$, we may use these two facts to reduce it to one of the following distinct words:
$$
\pm I, \pm A, \pm B, \pm AB.
$$
Thus, the group will have $8$ elements.